# Shorter code, prevent duplicated call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now I have code that looks like this:

```
def work_with_access_token_or_request_one
    if is_valid_access_token?(params[:code])
        request_client_with_access_token(params[:code])
    else
        request_access_token!
    end
end
```

In this method I **first check** if the code I get in the params is **valid**. 
If not I request one.

**My problem** is that right now the method `get_access_token` is **called twice**. Once when I check if the access_token is valid and the other time when I request the client.

```
def get_access_token(code)
    return Okto.request_access_token_from_code(code)
end
```

I have to do this because the output of `get_access_token(code)` returns when successful `{access_code: 89283}` or if an error occurred `{error: "not valid"}`

```
def is_valid_access_token?(code)
    result = get_access_token(code)
    return result[:access_code]
end

def request_client_with_access_token(code)
    result = get_access_token(code)
    client = Okto.get_client_from_access_code(result[:acess_code])
end
```

**How can I rewrite my code in `work_with_access_token_or_request_one` so that only once the method `get_access_token` is called?**  Thanks

Comment: Are `code` and `get_access_token(code)` logically equivalent? If they are then anything that works with a `code` should also work if given `get_access_token(code)`. Then you could monkey patch in a `code.to_access_token` method that would call `get_access_token(self)` on a code and would simply `return self` when called on an access token. Then codes could cache the token internally (or the caller could call `to_access_token`) and those two methods would just say `result = code.to_access_token` and not care what they're given. Might be ugly if everything is just strings and hashes though.

Comment: SO readers are mostly adults, so you don't need to bold-face certain words and phrases.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those methods belong to a single class. Then, you could rewrite your `get_access_token` method to *cache* the results like so:

```
def get_access_token(code)
    @access_token_cache ||= {}
    @access_token_cache[code] ||= Okto.request_access_token_from_code(code)
    @access_token_cache[code]
end
```

If that `code` should expire, then you can add that logic within your method as well.

Comment: Sorry but in this specific code I cant use class variable. Thanks for you inout. Do you maybe have another idea?

Comment: John, `@access_token_cache` is an instance variable, not a class variable.  `@@access_token_cache` is a class variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
def access_token(code)
  h = get_access_token(code)
  h.key?(:access_code) ? h[:access_code] : nil
end

def work_with_access_token_or_request_one
  result = access_token(@params[:code])
  result ? request_client_with_access_token(result) : request_access_token!
end
```

If you can change `get_access_token` and there is no untoward side effect, you could simplify:

```
def get_access_token(code)
  h = Okto.request_access_token_from_code(code)
  h.key?(:access_code) ? h[:access_code] : nil
end

def work_with_access_token_or_request_one
  result = get_access_token(@params[:code])
  result ? request_client_with_access_token(result) : request_access_token!
end
```

Note that the variable pointing to the hash must be an instance variable (`@params`) for the hash to be visible within the method.